# How to do multiple slicing in python without change np.array itself to save memory?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, slice

I have an np.array of dimension ~860,000. I want to discard one part of it every time and do some kind of calculation to the rest, e.g. I block [10000:20000] and use the rest, like I want the joint of data[:10000] and data[20000:]. However, I need iterate this process ~100t times. If I copy the array or create a new one every time, it will soon exceed memory of my cluster since the array dimension is too large. Is there any efficient way to do the slicing without change the array itself? Or is there any method that could reduce memory use as much as possible?

I tried to use np.append([:a],[b:]) every time but it exceeded memory.
Also tried np.roll(array, -num)[:-num] in order to only slice once, also exceeded memory

Comment: You could apply a formula where the limitation is a fraction of the total amount.
Cicle the process for the number of chuncks you could create, let's say every 100k so the first limitation goes with [1/8:2/8], and you can cicle the calculation 8 times. Then you can scale it as you need to not exceed memory.

Comment: I goes without saying that you shouldn't do things like for _ in range(0,8) and array[1/8:2/8] but instead create a real formula that stretches based on array lenght and chuncks needed.

Comment: calculate always the same array without passing that data to others, and if you need to save the data of each chunck put it files so you won't keep it in RAM while not using it.

Comment: thanks for your comments. For calculation, I need to joint [:1/8] and [2/8:], but anyway of pasting them together and create a new array would use memory. So I'm looking for a way that could slicing them based on the origin array

Comment: If you copy the data it'd be a waste of memory; I guess the key here is to chunck properly and to use the data every time by indexing it correctly. Here is some official documentation that can help: it's about [array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: actually, basic slicing in `numpy` creates a *view* so it is extremely memory (and time) efficient. However, `np.append` creates a new array every time. You should provide a little more details of what you are actually trying to accomplish

Comment: Once you've pulled two slices, do you need to keep the source array?  Temporarily, while concatenating them, you've increase memory usage, but if you can discard the source (along with the unused middle), the net usage should drop.  Same goes for each repeated slice.

Comment: Another way to visualize doing this selection is to make a `np.ones(arr, bool)`, and then with each iteration sets a new block of values to `False`.  And use this mask to select elements from the source array.  If your array is 1d, the mask with be just as large, and temporary selections will a significant fraction of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple trick that requires only ~3x the size of your original array `arr`.

From your attempt at using `np.roll` I take it you are ok with joining the two slices `arr[:a], arr[b:]` either way, so we will construct the equivalent of np.concatenate([arr[b:],arr[:a]])

This is a simple as

```
arrarr = np.concatenate([arr,arr])
N = arr.size
result = arrarr[b%N:N+a%N]
```

Since result is a simple slice into `arrarr` it does not copy any data. And obviously you can use the same `arrarr` for all slice pairs.

Comment: This is wonderful! I have solved this problem by freeing space using gc.collect. But thanks this trick is impressive!